# HTML Widgets not rendering correctly when using GoDaddy Managed Wordpress with Elementor

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor, godaddy-api

Trying to update our company website and adding a custom menu/album. It is GoDaddy hosted as a managed Wordpress site using Elementor to design. I have tried using the HTML widgets supplied and found that they are not working as expected. The code however works when I use it externally/locally in a regular html document. I have tried using either of the two widgets and have also updated all of the plugins/Elementor itself.

Note: I did have a prior image where it seemed like wordpress would not utilize the js files externally referenced, so I copied them locally into our file structure and referenced them from there. I apologize if any of this seems extremely stupid, I am not a very experienced coder/designer and was more or less just handed off this project as the shortest straw drawer.

[The widgets I am using:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VfgA.png)

[What it's supposed to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgOd.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.grafico.com/wp-content/plugins/GavinsWidget3/GavinsWidget3_Src/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nanogallery2@3/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.grafico.com/wp-content/plugins/GavinsWidget3/GavinsWidget3_Src/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
<!--MODIFY THE ALBUM GALLERY PREFERENCES HERE-->
    <div ID="ngy4p" data-nanogallery2='{
        "flickrAPIKey": "55bf5b423a3609849b017425cf1e3d88",
        "userID": "193200798@N04",
        "kind": "flickr",
        "thumbnailHeight":  200,
        "thumbnailWidth":   300,
        "allowList": "E+T",
        "thumbnailLabel": {
          "position": "overImageOnBottom",
          "align": "left"
        },
        "thumbnailAlignment": "center",
        "thumbnailOpenImage": true
      }'>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not entirely sure what it was, but if I had to guess I'd say there is a lag on some particular elements involved in our site as the html widgets are now rendering correctly...really bizarre. Other changes seem to happen close to instantaneously however so I am not entirely sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually mentioned in your comments what it is you are trying to achieve and what is wrong with the code. Please give some details as I am completely confused by your post.